# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in synapse

Tags: oracle, azure-synapse

```
qu = 'SELECT DS.TABLESPACE_NAME AS SCHEMA_NAME,
             SEGMENT_NAME AS TABLE_NAME,
             ROUND(SUM(DS.BYTES) / (1024 * 1024)) AS MB
        FROM DBA_SEGMENTS DS
       WHERE SEGMENT_NAME IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME
                                FROM DBA_TABLES)
       GROUP BY DS.TABLESPACE_NAME, SEGMENT_NAME;'
```

When I'm executing this query in the synapse notebook, it says "missing right parenthesis".
Can anyone help pls?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be OK, unless you need to remove the terminating semi-colon:

```
... GROUP BY DS.TABLESPACE_NAME, SEGMENT_NAME;'
                                             ^
                                             |
                                           here
```

Query itself runs OK:

```
SQL> SELECT ds.tablespace_name AS schema_name,
  2         segment_name       AS table_name,
  3         round(SUM(ds.bytes)/(1024 * 1024)) AS mb
  4  FROM dba_segments ds
  5  WHERE segment_name IN (SELECT table_name
  6                         FROM dba_tables
  7                        )
  8  GROUP BY ds.tablespace_name,
  9           segment_name;

SCHEMA_NAME                    TABLE_NAME         MB
------------------------------ ---------- ----------
SYSTEM                         OBJ$                2
SYSTEM                         UNDO$               0
SYSTEM                         FILE$               0
<snip>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I remove the terminating semi-colon, it says " SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: Hm ... query is correctly written, it runs OK on my 11gXE Oracle database - see an example I posted. Maybe it has to do something with the tool you use.